Minkowski's Lattice Point Theorem on Linear Forms
I am reading Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory and I was stuck at exercise 3 on page 28. Here is the exercise:

Let $$L_i(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}x_j,\hspace{0.5cm}i=1,2,\cdots,n$$ be real linear forms such that $\det(a_{ij})\ne 0$. Let $c_i$ be positive real numbers such that $c_1\cdots c_n>|\det(a_{ij})|$. Show that there exist integers $m_1,\cdots,m_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $$|L_i(m_1,\cdots,m_n)|<c_i$$ for all $i=1,2,\cdots,n$.

I was thinking of using the Minkowski's Lattice Point Theorem, but I can't see there the lattice or the inequality is. Can someone help me out?
Below are the full statement of the Minkowski's Lattice Point Theorem (a complete lattice is a lattice that spans the whole vector space).


Set $Y = \{x : |x_i| < c_i\}$.  Then $\mbox{Vol}(Y) = 2^n\prod_i c_i$. Set $X = L^{-1}(Y)$ which has $\mbox{Vol}(X) = 2^n \prod c_i/\det (a_{ij}) > 2^n$.  Apply Minkowski's theorem with $\Gamma$ the lattice of points with integer coordinates.
